# Javascript button to call custom fields data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create [this button](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst) for a custom field that I have on my website

```
<button type="button"
        onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
        Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
```

The thing is, when i hit the button to show me the input from a custom field that I have on my wordpress site. I put the name on the field instead of '`Date()`' and the id of the div i have but nothing happens.  Problem is i don't know what code should I write in order to do just that.

Update(based on brownian): So, this is an infographic that explains better what i need:
[image: what i want to achieve]

[image: how it looks the custom field element]

Comment: Show the code you are working with, not some generic example code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you wish to achieve?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
     onclick="var the_id=document.getElementById('my_field').value;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=
        document.getElementById(the_id).innerHTML;">
Click me to display some other string.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<input id="my_field" type="text"></a>

<div id="someother">Hi there!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if instead of text i put the id of the field and instead of id="text" i replace it with id="my_field" it still doesn't show anything :/

Comment: If instead you explain what you want to *achieve* --- not to break... ,) Ok, I've updated my answer --- is that what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Brownian, I just updated my question with a graphic explaingin better what I am trying to get. Hope it explains better. 
PS: I have tried you updated code, but no luck. I am not sure what do I do wrong. I have written the code in the picture

Comment: So, if you replace "not working" with "working" this will work. I don't know where email is stored actually.

Comment: instead of 'not working' i want it to show the email address that was enter inside the custom field

Comment: I am sorry, there is no any custom field in your code. I can not see or guess where is that email data. I am sorry. Try to re-word your question and code. Try to show what you are actually writing and trying to make working.

Comment: I have posted a screen shot of the custom field (it is via Custom Fields plugin, i have no code for that, the plugin does the magic) 

to illustrate, I will show you the code I use for displaying a different custom field, that shows when the page is loaded, without needing a button for it, that is for "description":
<?php
if(get_field('description'))
{
 echo '<div class="the_description">This is the description: </div>';
 echo '<p>' . get_field('description') . '</p>';
}
?>